# Access denied 403 errors after migrating my site

Tags: joomla, 403-forbidden

I've recently migrated my Joomla site from one shared hosting to another with Hostgator. GWT notified me about many 403 access denied pages. I've checked with Firebug too, and even though browser is displaying full page correctly but http return is 403. I've checked the home page but it's correctly returing 200 response.

The same is shown by Fetch as Google in GWT(pasted this in the bottom).

The site is 3 years old and I regularly do such migrations. I've copied the files and database "AS IS". I've even cleared all the caches but no luck.

There is only one change: previously the site was primary domain but now it's add-on one.

What could be the issue?

This is how Googlebot fetched the page.

**Fetch as Google**

```
URL: http://MYSITE.COM/-----------------REMOVED.html

Date: Thursday, June 20, 2013 at 10:32:14 PM PDT

Googlebot Type: Web

Download Time (in milliseconds): 3899

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 05:32:15 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"
Expires: Mon, 1 Jan 2001 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: 0e4f6b53991c80cf39d57a6db58bb58d=ee2d880e8db0f1fc03c5612ea5a77004; path=/
Last-Modified: Fri, 21 Jun 2013 05:32:19 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=75
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-gb" lang="en-gb" >
<head>
  <base href="http://www.mysite.com/-----------------rajiv-yuva-shakthi-programme-finance-planning.html" />
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="" />

<<<<<<TRIMMED>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess you have .htaccess which uses mod_rewrite, and does not like your new subdomain for some reason. (If you had published your real URL, it might provide more info for debugging...)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for a line where the domain is listed in the .htaccess and check if it is correct (I guess it is).

Now look for a line with:

```
RewriteBase /
```

and change the / to /name-of-the-folder-under-public-html/
Check with FTP to find out the name of the folder, or better yet, set a specific name yourself when creating the add-on domain.

In the rewriteBase line, it will need the correct path on the account (below public_html), even if the domain need to open a separate site.